# How do I append all the query results to a datagrigridView?

Tags: c#

So basically I am trying to append all the results from the foreach loop query to the datagrid2 but I just don't get it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row != null)
            {
                string col1 = row.Cells["F2"].Value.ToString();
                string col2 = row.Cells["F3"].Value.ToString();
                string col3 = row.Cells["F9"].Value.ToString();
                string like = "'" + "%" + col3 + col1 + col2 + "%" + "'";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    string query = string.Format("query" + like);
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = query;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                        try
                        {
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            dAdapter.Fill(dt);
                            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
                        }
                        catch (Exception exceptionObject)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(exceptionObject.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The basic problem is that you're re-binding the data source for the grid in every iteration of the loop, so it will only show what's from the last iteration.  *However*, I really wonder if you need a loop here at all.  Querying a database in a loop *usually* isn't a good idea.  What is the purpose of doing that here?  Can you use a loop to build a *single* query and then bind the grid to the results of that query?

Comment: Don't call that datatable constructor : DataTable dt = new DataTable();  Calling the DataTable clears the table so you loose old data.  Just call the constructor before 1st query.

Comment: @David The reason for doing that is that I am taking each row from the datagrid1 and building a new query for each row.

Comment: @TonyBatista: The reason you are querying once for each row is because you are querying once for each row?  That's not a reason, that's a tautology.  What are the resulting queries and why can't they be combined?